# Import RGB value of each pixel in an image to 1-D array

Tags: python

How to import RGB value of each pixel in an image to 1-D array?

I am using following thing:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
pix = im.load()
print pix[x,y]
```

this imports it into 2-D array which is not iterable. 
I want this same thing but in 1-D array.

Comment: You mean that you want to flatten a 2D array into a 1D array? There are [many ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) to do that...

Comment: For that method to work it should support iteration. But the pix array doesn't.

Comment: You're quite right! See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the pixels into a 1D array as follows:

```
width, height = im.size
pixels = [pix[i, j] for i in range(width) for j in range(height)]
```

Comment: It is a good solution but it is messing up the order of original array. The 1-D array which I want should be something like(assuming i to be row numbers in 2-D array):
row i then row i+1 right behind that ith row and so on. Just like how compiler goes.

Comment: @VikasBansal: I don't understand the order you want. Do you want `(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)...(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)...` or do you want `(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)...(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)...`

Comment: In that case, the above solution *should* give you the answer you want. Can you show an example of a case where it doesn't?

Comment: Lets say the number of rows and columns in original array were N. Now if you pull the value of last element in 2-D array that is pix[N-1,N-1], it is not the same value as in new 1-d array pixel[(N-1)*(N-1)].

Comment: @VikasBansal: It should be the same. Are you sure that your image is a square image that is N by N? (Try running `pix[width - 1, height - 1] == pixels[-1]` after my code)

Answer (score 1):

Easy if you're using numpy, and no need to load the image.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")

pix_flatiter = np.asarray(im).flat  # is an iterable
```

If you want to load the whole array, you can do:

```
pix_flat = np.asarray(im).flatten() # is an array
```